# Android Navigation - Is there a way to clear all saveState's to force reload every screen when navigating next time?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using Jetpack Compose Navigation and I'm saving the state and call restoreState when navigating through the app to not reload the lists every time. But I don't want this behaviour when one user blocks another. After blocking, it should hide all content from the blocked user in every list around the app. But when it always restores the state, the posts of that user are still contained inside the lists.

I would like to "clear the cache"/clear all the saved states after the user blocks another, so that when he navigates, every screen launches the LaunchedEffect(Unit) again and fetches the updated list, without the blocked users' posts, from the backend.

How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this method:

> Clears any saved state associated with route that was previously saved via popBackStack when using a saveState value of true.

```
navController.clearBackStack("route_name")
```

And you can get all back stack entry routes using this:

```
val routes = navController.backQueue.map { it.destination.route }
```